# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enqueueSetState' of undefined

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I am trying to call this function with a parameter to map filterCategories but I got this error.

```
            interface FrontPageComponents {
                filterCategories: GetTheActivity[];
            }
        
            export class FrontPage extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, FrontPageComponents> {
        
        constructor() {
                super();
                this.state = {filterCategories: []};
        
        }
            public sort(event: string) {   
            
                    
                     console.log(event);
                     return (
            
                         $.ajax({
                             type: "POST",
                             url: './Categ/GetFilterCategories',
                             dataType: 'json',
                             data: { _event: event },
                             success: (response) => {
                                 FrontPage.prototype.setState({                     //in this line the error
                                     filterCategories: response
                                 }) }
                         })
                         
                         );
                    
            
            
                } 
    
    public render() {
    return      <div>
    <Sorting />
    </div>;
    
    }   

}
```

in sorting component, I call the function like that:

```
FrontPage.prototype.sort(event.target.innerText);
```

Comment: `FrontPage.prototype.setState.call(this, { ... })`. But why aren't you calling `setState()` directly?

Comment: I did both of those suggestions I got the same error even directly. Always says filterCategories not define.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
FrontPage.prototype.setState({
    filterCategories: response
})
```

just do

```
this.setState({ filterCategories: response })
```

Since, you're using arrow functions, `this` will still be correct.

Comment: I use it inside sorting component in a function called:

  select(event: any) {
        
        this.setState({
            dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen,
            value: event.target.innerText
            
         });

        FrontPage.prototype.sort(event.target.innerText);

    }

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `this` is not defined is because if you call `this` inside the ajax success method `this` refers to the scope of the response.

Try to do something like: `const that = this;` above the ajax request. Afterwards in the success method call `that.setState(...)`. In this scenario `that` refers to the current instance of the component.

I know it is a dirty fix, but it works.